# User defined struct conversion as function's default parameter

Tags: c#, casting, default-parameters

```
public struct MyInt
{
    public int csInt;

    public MyInt(int i)
    {
        csInt = i;
    }

    public MyInt(double d)
    {
        csInt = (int)d;
    }

    public static implicit operator MyInt(int value)
    {
        return new MyInt(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator MyInt(double value)
    {
        return new MyInt(value);
    }
}


int MyFunc(MyInt i = 0)
{
    return -1;
}
```

I want to implement a wrapper struct`MyInt` (simplified here) to accept `int` as default value (I know this is weird and unnatural, I just need it to comply other language format), but I meet error when I code like above, the error is at `int MyFunc(MyInt i = 0)` where VS2012 said:

> a value of type 'int' cannot be used as a default parameter because there are no standard conversions to Type MyInt

As I know, int and double also defined as struct in C#. So I have tried follows:

```
int MyFunc(double i = (int)0)
{
return -1;
}
```

It passed! Therefore I think type conversion is allowed in default parameter.

So my questions are:

1. Why can not use implicit type conversion for MyInt as default para?
2. What does the **standard conversions** mean in VS error message, is it diff from implicit conversion defined in MyInt?

Answer (score 1):

Implicit conversion operators are **methods**, and you cannot use methods (or event static fields) as default parameters - only **constants** are allowed (which makes sense, since the compiler will actually use these constants anywhere you call the method.)

In your case, since you want the default value of the struct (i.e. all fields initialized to 0), you can use the `default` keyword:

```
int MyFunc(MyInt i = default(MyInt))
{
    return -1;
}
```

C# standard conversions are conversions the compiler can perform on its own (like Int32 to Double or any type to Object). You can read all about them in the [C# Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/specifications).

Comment: Yes, default keyword can resolve part of my problem, but not for the case where the users want to set their own default value of my defined struct, such as MyInt, when they create their defined function. E.g. int JimFunc(MyInt i = JimDefaulttInt). Look forward to your help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you try this:

```
int MyFunc(MyInt i = (MyInt)0)
```

You get an error

> Default parameter value for 'i' must be a compile-time constant

Which tells you why it can't work - at compile-time, there's no way to tell how to convert the `0` you typed into a `MyInt` (since your operator code runs at run-time).

It works for `double` because the C# compiler knows about that type; it's not user-defined.

You can work around it by defining an overload instead of using a default parameter value:

```
int MyFunc(MyInt i)
{
    return -1;
}

int MyFunc()
{
    return MyFunc((MyInt)0);
}
```

Comment: I see. One more question, is there any methods to achieve similar implementation? Thank you, Blorgbeard~